# how to process Aws kinesis stream processing using lambda function in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services

we are posting huge data  streaming into `aws kinesis` stream with 6 shard from various sources, and then processing the stream using single `aws lamda` subscribe to kinesis stream to process the records.

In real time we are seeing huge lag time, huge data in waiting yet to be processed.

How we can handle this scenario in severless architecture ?

Is it possible to subscribe to particular shard in `aws lamda` or create multiple aws lamda to subscribe the same kinesis stream?

Comment: Do the Amazon CloudWatch metrics indicate a high number of concurrent executions of the Lambda function? If they are hitting the default limit of 1000 concurrent functions, you could request the limit be increased. If, on the other hand, it is a low number, it might be an indication that the data is being processed sequentially for each shard and the data is coming in too fast for the Lambda function to process sequentially.

Comment: The processing time of lambda is an important factor, if per say lambda take 10s to complete processing 1 batch of records (1000 records), but every 10s there's incoming 2000 records per shark, obviously lag time is expected.

The more expensive way is to simply increase the number of shard, this allow more concurrent Lambda invocations (1 invocation per shard by default)

Or you can playaround with Batch Size & Batch Windows setting & see if it could help reducing the processing time.

Comment: Another new feature to look at: Parallelization Factor which allow lambda to invoke more than 1 execution per shard
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-aws-lambda-scaling-controls-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/